# How to send a question from an external resource too IBM Watson assistant so that the chatbot can answer

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have a speech to text converter implemented in python and I want the text result to be sent to the chatbot so that it can answer me.

Example:

Guy (voice): I need my bank account info
The code translates that to text and sends "I need my bank account info" to the chatbot.
The chatbot then replies with bank account info or anything (doesnt matter)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Python SDK, amongst others, that will allow you to interact with the Watson Assistant service - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=python

The flow is:

- authenticate
- create a session
- send a message

You will of course need to create the assistant dialog - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-getting-started

Comment: You also need to create at least one intent with some examples :-)